# How to convert a "custom class" to an arraylist?nc

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a class called student. Student class has public fields like first name, and last name. I am creating an instance of this class in my default page and assigning values to the fields. I have a function which takes two arraylists and return false if items in the arraylists do not match. In my default page, I have an arraylist which has items like first name and last name. I am passing this student object and the arraylist to compare and I get unable to cast Student to arraylist. Is there a way to work around this? Below is my code.

```
Dim valid as boolean = StudentsCompare(Student, arrlst)

Function StudentsCompare(ByVal arraylist1 as Arraylist, ByVal arrayList2 as ArrayList)

    Dim Error As Boolean = True

    For i As Integer = 0 To (arraylist1.Count - 1)


        If Not arraylist1.Item(i).ToString = arrayList2.Item(i).ToString Then
            Return Error = False
        End If
    Next

        Return Error

End Function
```

Comment: You should use `List<T>`, not `ArrayList`.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for the reply. Should I use the list<t> in the function?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way; `student.FirstName` is an example you may need to change it with one of your class's real property.

```
Private valid As Boolean = StudentsCompare(List(Of Student), arrlst)

Private Function StudentsCompare(students As List(Of Student), list As ArrayList) As   Boolean
  Dim index As Integer = 0
  For Each student As var In students
     If student.FirstName = list(index).ToString() Then
        Return False
     End If
      index += 1
  Next
  Return True
End Function
```

And If you have both parameter with the same object "Student" you could do it this way and check the multiple conditions:

```
Private list1 As List(Of Student)
Private list2 As List(Of Student)

Private valid As Boolean = StudentsCompare(list1, list2)

Private Function StudentsCompare(students1 As List(Of Student), students2 As List(Of Student)) As Boolean
    For Each st1 As var In students1
        For Each st2 As var In students2
            If st1.FirstName = st2.FirstName AndAlso st1.LastName = st2.LastName AndAlso st1.Grade = st2.Grade Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, I have other fields for the student object like last name, grade year, etc. How would I check for the other fields with your implementation style?

Comment: what is the value of the arrlst ? is it an object of the Student ? in another word is it the same format as List(Of Student) ?

Comment: yup, arrlst has items which are the same type as student object fields.

Comment: then you could just simply replace the second array list with another `List(Of Student)` method and check all the conditions that you need.

Comment: I am getting this error. "Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Student' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Student]'." Sorry, I am begginer in vb.net